# Inner Join laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, laravel-5

Fellow Coders,

I'm trying to use an inner join query to get multiple data from my relative tables.. What i'm trying to do is to get the (`project_id` as `company_name` - `subproject_id` as `subproject_title`). I tried to use the query as I will state below. Also I will post printscreens of my tables.

```
$values = DB::table('hour_registrations')->join('projects', 'id', '=', 'id')->join('subprojects','id', '=', 'id')->select('projects.*', 'id', 'subprojects.id')->get();
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would love some help with my question as I do not understand what to do now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick (if I understood your table structure correctly).

I would encourage you to read the official Laravel documentation on [Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins).

```
$query = DB::table('projects')
           ->join('subprojects', 'projects.id', '=', 'subprojects.project_id')
           ->join('companies', 'projects.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
           ->select('companies.company_name', 'projects.id', 'subprojects.id', 'subprojects.title')
           ->get();
```

Comment: Yeah I checked out the docs, I also asked a colleague. But yet again I am a complete rookie in queries etc. etc. But I really appreciate the help. I'll try it out asap

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'companies.title' in 'field list' (SQL: select `companies`.`title`, `projects`.`project_id`, `subprojects_id`, `subprojects`.`title` from `projects` inner join `subprojects` on `projects`.`subproject_id` = `subprojects`.`id` inner join `companies` on `projects`.`project_id` = `companies`.`project_id`                         This is quite an interesting error, as I am looking at the table right now and I do not see a 'companies.title' anywhere, if you could check it out again I would appreciate it. I will try to fix it myself aswell

Comment: I edited the query. The dump of the screenshots didn't really help. Also, the documentation is fairly straightforward and it is not difficult to figure it out.

Comment: I really REALLY gotta thank you man.. If I could give you money I'd damn sure do it. I'm on the edge of being fired as an intern because of my lack of programming skills... And yeah it really is straight forward now that I'm looking at it... I don't know maybe i'm just dumb or I just didn't really understand it

Comment: I dump died the variable, and yes I get the requested values. What I need to do now is to loop it in a dropdown in my view as (project_id as company_name - subproject_id as subproject_title). which is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Easy enough. Good luck!

Comment: Well, I looped through it. But now it's complaining that I am trying to fill in the "PROJECT_ID" field with something else. The company_name in this case...

Comment: You should post a new question or at the very least add it to the above question. Our discussion has no context now based on your previous question and neither does the answer. It wouldn't help others. Can you edit it back and post a new one?

Comment: Would you be interested to go in a chatbox so you could assist me there further?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143249/discussion-between-kayelder-and-mozammil-khodabacchas).