# Laravel constraint error

Tags: php, laravel, loops

After I filled in the dropdown menu with a forloop using the data of the inner join query that had been made. Everything was shown in the dropdown menu as it should. (company_name - task title). But when I press on save, my ajax throws an error which I will paste below.

```
<td> <select class='project_id'>@foreach($query as $data)<option>{!!  $data->company_name !!} - {!! $data->title !!}</option>@endforeach</td>
```

is the piece of code I use to loop through the query and to post the values in the dropdown menu

The printscreen of a part of the query and the values is posted below:
[image]
The error I get when I press the save button is.

[image]

If I check the object that gets sent via my ajax request. I see this:

[image]

Comment: Im pretty sure `"LMS BVBA"` is not a valid `project_id`. Its probably a name or sth. Make sure the option of your `option` as sth. like `value="{{$data->id}}"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not submitting the actual project id with the request which is needed.

Make sure the `option` value contains the project id and that is has the name set to `project_id` if that's what you are using on the server-side.

```
<td> <select class="project_id" name="project_id">@foreach($query as $data)<option value="{{ $data->id }}">{!!  $data->company_name !!} - {!! $data->title !!}</option>@endforeach</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a foreign key constraint, it says you want to add or update some project id which is not found in the projects table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753747/inner-join-laravel-5-2/43754191?noredirect=1#comment74551594_43754191 I will refer to this question I asked a bit earlier.. In the someone helped me with an inner join query that should get the project_id aswell. I am confused as to why it doesn't work. Could you or anyone perhaps help? Would appreciate it