# Onchange dropdown selecting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel

Fellow Coders,

I have 2 dropdown menu's in which the first one contains a list of companies. And the other one contains a list of tasks. What I need to do now is to get the corresponding tasks linked to the company_name (project ID).

So in short. If I open the dropdown and select a company (project_ID). I need the tasks (subproject_ID) linked to that project.

Also, if one specific company has been chosen then the second dropdown should also have the corresponding tasks BUT a new field has to be added in the row that adds my data to the database called note.

If anyone has some sort of an idea how I could do this. that would be greatly appreciated. I also linked some of the table prints in my other question for reference.

[Inner Join laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753747/inner-join-laravel-5-2/43754191#43754191)

Comment: Can you post what code you actually have now?

Comment: You pretty much bind an ajax call to the onchange event for the dropdown. Then iterate over the content you receive back and replace the second dropdowns content with that.

Comment: So basically, use ajax when an onchange function has been triggered. And use that ajax call to edit the values in the second dropdown?

Comment: That's the point, I do have a blank ajax with an onchane jquery function. But I have no clue how I can tell it that when a company has been chosen. That the specific values corresponding to the company will be shown in the second dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your previous questions, this could do the trick

```
<select name="project_id">
    <option value="{{ $data->project_id }}">{{ $data->company_name }}</option>
</select>

<select name="subproject">
    <option value="{{ $data->subproject_id }}" data-project="{{ $data->project_id }}">{{ $data->title }}</option>
</select>

<textarea name="note" style="display: none" disabled></textarea>

<script>
$("select[name='project_id']").on('change', function()
{
    var project_id = $(this).value;
    $("select[name='subproject'] > option[data-project != "+ project_id +"]").hide();

    if(project_id == 1)
    {
        var note = $("textarea[name='note']"); 
        note.show();
        note.prop("disabled", false); 
    }
})
</script>
```

You have the two dropdowns. The second dropdown's option contains another data-attribute that will specifiy the project id and based on that you can either hide/show the option values you want. The ideal solution is to use AJAX and get the appropriate values but *this* should work too.

You just need to bind to the `onchange` event on the first dropdown and do some logic (based on the project id) to hide the value of the options you don't need in the second dropdown.

To add the note field, you can do the same. If the `project_id` matches the company that you need, you can enable the textarea that you want.

I hope this answers your questions.